# execute .exe from php in desktop interface

Tags: php, localhost, exec, executable

How to execute a program from php i use the following code:

```
$filePath = 'C:\AppServ\www\eval\bot.au3';

exec("C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c START " . $filePath);
```

when i execute the code the bot.au3 start but not in my interface,

[image: the message i get]

it take me to an other interface when i click View the message where the file bot.au3 is executing

i want bot.au3 to be executed in my desktop interface

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to run this on the server where PHP is? Or are you trying to run it on the client?

Comment: taking the same action if i wrote START C:\AppServ\www\eval\bot.au3 in cmd

Comment: for example website installer on windows vps when user visite the page where the code is C:\AppServ\www\eval\bot.au3 executing in the vps desktop